# Unable to get gRPC to work in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin

I have created a Xamarin Android project. Via NuGet, I have added a reference to the **Grpc** package.

In my activity, I want to create a Grpc.Core.Server instance, but it won't let me because of the following runtime error:

*System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Error loading native library. Not found in any of the possible locations: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/DecodingPoC.DecodingPoC/files/.**override**/libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.so,/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/DecodingPoC.DecodingPoC/files/.**override**/runtimes/linux/native/libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.so,/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/DecodingPoC.DecodingPoC/files/.**override**/../../runtimes/linux/native/libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.so*

I haven't been able to find any information on this for Xamarin, only iOS, so I am hoping someone here can provide a suggestion on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that gRPC c# support for Xamarin is currently experimental. The stable packages in nuget.org don't provide the support yet (that will change with the upcoming v1.15.x release).

See HelloWorldXamarin instructions on how to obtain the correct nuget package (or use the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Core/1.15.0-pre1 pre-release package which already supports Xamarin):
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/csharp/HelloworldXamarin#experimental-only

You might also need this workaround if you are using Xamarin.Forms: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/16250